# Creating sites using graph api

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I was wondering if there is an eta on when it is possible withing Graph to create Sites / subsites directly instead of using the sharepoint rest api's?

Answer (score 0):

No ETA to share unfortunately.  If you're starting fresh today, I would recommend using the SharePoint PNP Provisioning engine if possible, it's highly likely that when we do introduce provisioning APIs to Microsoft Graph we'll update the PNP Provisioning engine to take advantage of them.

Comment: Hello Jeremy, 

thanks for the information. I'm a Java developer and are just starting with the sharepoint api / environment.  Do you have any good documentations / links that can point me in the right direction how to provision using java? (if that is even possible)